# Problem with lines 8.21-8.22 of Ovids Amores 1.8

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, ovidius

The sentence is:

"illa monebat talia (mē duplicēs occuluēre forēs)"

So the first part I'm pretty sure I've got correct. I have it as:

"that distinguished witch (antecedant is  Dipsas) warned me"

However for the next part I'm really lost, "dedeces" is a subjunctive second person present active plural verb, but then the notes say that "occuluere" is an indicative third person perfect active plural verb. I'm not sure what to do with these, and I can't really make sense of why "dedeces" is subjunctive. My best guess would be something like:

"The doors you would double have hidden me"

But that treats "fores" as both subject and accusative, which I guess is not unheard of, and also is kind of a cop out regarding the subjunctive mood here.

Any help wold be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you post a few lines of the passage so that we see at least the whole sentence? More context without having to look it up would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me that you have simply misread the adjective "duplices" as the verb "dedeces" (which does not appear in the text).

*occuluere* is thus the only verb in the clause, with *duplices fores* as its subject.

Comment: I see, duplices also happens to be the 2nd person present subjunctive from of duplico. I think thats where my issue lied.